# Codenmae one toolbar height

Tags: java, toolbar, codenameone

I have a problem in getting the height of my toolbar.

Before adding components the height is "0" and the same result after adding components.

So, is there a way to get the real toolbar height?

```
btnCnt = new Container();
btnCnt.setUIID(null);
btnCnt.addComponent(btnBack);
btnCnt.addComponent(btnHome);
btnCnt.addComponent(btnExit);

currentForm.setToolBar(homeToolBar);
currentForm.addCommand(SideLogoCommand);
homeToolBar.addCommandToSideMenu(MenuCommand);
homeToolBar.setTitleComponent(btnLogo);

Container commandCnt = new Container(new BorderLayout());
commandCnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, btnCnt);
commandCnt.setUIID(null);
commandCnt.setPreferredH(homeToolBar.getHeight());
stateMachine.findCntHomeV2Header(currentForm).removeAll();
stateMachine.findCntHomeV2Header(currentForm).repaint();
stateMachine.findCntHomeV2Header(currentForm).addComponent(commandCnt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `setSameHeight()` not `setPrefferedH()`.

`setPrefferedH()` is deprecated.

Though if you still want to do it that way, use `homeToolBar.getPreferredH()` and not `homeToolBar.getHeight()`

```
btnCnt = new Container();
btnCnt.setUIID(null);
btnCnt.addComponent(btnBack);
btnCnt.addComponent(btnHome);
btnCnt.addComponent(btnExit);

currentForm.setToolBar(homeToolBar);
currentForm.addCommand(SideLogoCommand);
homeToolBar.addCommandToSideMenu(MenuCommand);
homeToolBar.setTitleComponent(btnLogo);


Container commandCnt = new Container(new BorderLayout());
commandCnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, btnCnt);
commandCnt.setUIID(null);
Component.setSameHeight(homeToolBar, commandCnt);
stateMachine.findCntHomeV2Header(currentForm).removeAll();
stateMachine.findCntHomeV2Header(currentForm).repaint();
stateMachine.findCntHomeV2Header(currentForm).addComponent(commandCnt);
```